# How do I return a certain date into a textbox based on a DateTimePicker date using VB.net Framework 8.0?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, formula

I am creating a desktop version of a program that I use a DateTimePicker formatted as Short.  I have a textbox that I want to display a date based on the DateTimePicker with a very specific formula.  I've looked all over the internet and can't find an answer to this very specific need.

I do not have code to share at this moment.  Here is a rundown of what I do have.

I have the Date in the DateTimePicker.
I have the Textbox where I want the new date.
I have a formula that I need to apply to the DateTimePicker value.

The formula is X = DateTimePicker + (Y * 30).

Pretty basic but I can't figure out how to "Marry" the DateTimePicker value with the formula and get a new date.

I tried different methods based on research from forums, including StackOverflow but have had no success.

I'm hoping someone will be able to help me in getting this to work.

Comment: A couple of confusing things here - do you mean .Net Framework 4.8, or do you mean .Net 8.0?

Comment: Is "Y" just a numeric value?

Comment: You should be able to get <DateTimePicker>.value, which will give you a DateTime object, then use a method such as .AddDays or .AddHours (or whatever other time interval increment you need)

Comment: I would suggest that, rather than looking all over the internet, you should have started by reading the documentation for the `DateTimePicker` class. If you'd done that then you'd know that you can get a `DateTime` value from the `Value` property of the control. That's the end of the relevance of the `DateTimePicker` and now your question is about manipulating `DateTime` values. Reading the documentation for that type would show you how to do that, e.g. `AddMonths` or `AddDays` method. ALWAYS read the relevant documentation.

Comment: What is `Y` in your formula? I suspect that it is actually a number of months and you are assuming that all months are 30 days. If you want to add a number of days then `AddDays` is obviously what you want, which you should have found in the documentation. If you actually want to add a number of months then you should use `AddMonths`, which will actually take into account the different length of each month. That should also have been found via the documentation.

Comment: For the record, you can immediately open the documentation for a type or member by clicking on it in the VS code window and pressing F1. Context-sensitive Help in Windows has been a thing for decades. I think that works in the designer too. You should also favourite/bookmark the API reference home page in your browser. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/) is the Australian version I use. You can get there from the Help menu is VS but it takes some extra clicks that aren't as obvious as they might be.

Comment: @Craig, I'm building my application using .Net Framework 8.0.  The "Y" in my example represents the answer that would go into the future date textbox, after converting back to a date format of course.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I admit, I did not try the documentation in Visual Studio because my situation is fairly unique, at least that's what I was assuming.  I will take a look there.

Like I mention to Craig, the "Y" in my example represents the answer that would go into the future date textbox, after converting back to a date format of course.

Comment: @Craig, It's actually just .NET 8.0 not Framework.

Comment: You say that Y is the result you want to display but X is the actual result of the formula so surely that's what you want to display. Y is some multiplication factor, but what?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, My bad.  I was reading the comments while very tired.  You are correct.  X is the actual result.  Y is a Double number from another textbox.

Comment: But what does `Y` actually represent? Obviously it's a number or you wouldn't be multiplying it, but what does the number mean? Like I said, it looks to me like it could be a number of months but that's just an educated guess.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, here is the actual formula.

SecondDate = DateTimePicker + (EstimatedHoldTime(InMonths) * 30)

I am trying to get SecondDate based on this formula.  Not adding months or a certain amount of days.  SecondDate is a Textbox, DateTimePicker is a DateTimePicker Box, EstimatedHoldTime(Months) is a Textbox As Double, 30 is a Fixed Number.

Comment: I'm not going to say that what you're doing is wrong because I don't know the requirements for your scenario but saying *"Not adding months or a certain amount of days"* is obviously completely false. Your own formula makes it plain that you are adding a number of months with the assumption that each month contains 30 days. If that assumption is appropriate then you should obviously be calling `AddDays` and passing the result of that multiplication. If that assumption is not appropriate then you should obviously be calling `AddMonths` and passing the value without multiplying by 30.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, Understood.  I'm thinking now you are probably correct.  I wasn't looking at the formula that way, but what you say does make sense.  I'm trying the code from Idle_Mind but still have an issue.  I'll keep you posted.  Thanks for the communications and especially for making me see what I should have seen in the formula before.  :)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> here is the actual formula. SecondDate = DateTimePicker +
> (EstimatedHoldTime(InMonths) * 30) I am trying to get SecondDate based
> on this formula. Not adding months or a certain amount of days.
> SecondDate is a Textbox, DateTimePicker is a DateTimePicker Box,
> EstimatedHoldTime(Months) is a Textbox As Double, 30 is a Fixed Number

Here's an example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim value As Double
    If (Double.TryParse(EstimatedHoldTime(Months).Text, value)) Then
        Dim dt As DateTime = DateTimePicker.Value.AddDays(value * 30)
        SecondDate.Text = dt.ToShortDateString()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Hold Time!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: that seems to get me closer.  Let me see if I understand what is going on.  First: Setting "value" as a Double.  Second: Checking to see if EstimatedHoldTime(Months).Text is indeed a Double and assigning it to "value".  Third: Setting "dt" as DatTime which then equals the DateTimePicker value and adding the estimated hold time "value" * 30 to it.  Fourth: Putting "dt" into the seconddate textbox as a Short date.  Else: throw an error text message.  I know there are different ways to do the same thing so I want to be sure I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: That perfectly describes what the code is doing. Once you get your formula ironed out I'm sure you'll be able to apply it.

Comment: Hey Guys, I got it working.  Here's what I did to get me the correct answer.

txtPRPAAssumesSaleIsOnOrBefore.Text = dtDate.Value.ToOADate + (txtPVPEsitmatedHoldTimeMonths.Text * 30)
Dim NewDate As Date = Date.FromOADate(txtPRPAAssumesSaleIsOnOrBefore.Text)
NewDate.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")
txtPRPAAssumesSaleIsOnOrBefore.Text = NewDate.ToShortDateString

FYI, I updated a couple names.